# Getting parts of a string and combine them in C#?

Tags: c#, string

I have a string like this: *C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg*

Now, what I want to do is to dynamically combine the last 4 numbers, in this case its **10000080** as result. My idea was ti split this and combine them in some way, is there an easier way? I cant rely on the array index, because the path can be longer or shorter as well.

Is there a nice way to do that?

Thanks :)

Comment: would regex be a solution? What are your exact requirements?

Comment: The exact requirement is to get those 4 numbers from any given path. The numbers will always be there, but not always at the same place in the string. I thought about regex as well, but maybe there is another solution?

Comment: @grady C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\  this dir is constant? and 10\00\00\80\ are constantly in this structure? give a quick reply so that i can help you!!!!

Comment: No, the c:\... part is not constant, the number are always the same structure, but the numbers itself change, can be 100\87\009\9871, too.

Comment: so there could be a folder after the number? Like 
C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\some\folder\test.jpg

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use String.[Split](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.split.aspx)

```
String toSplit = "C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg";
String[] parts = toSplit.Split(new String[] { @"\" });

String result = String.Empty;
for (int i = 5, i > 1; i--)
{
   result += parts[parts.Length - i];
}

// Gives the result 10000080
```

Comment: This only works if there are no subfolders after the number. This alogrithm would be quite unhandy if there is a undefined depth of subfolders given. for example: C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\some\folder\test.jpg

Comment: @oberfreak: His question does specify that the numbers are always in the same structure (I assume that means place)

Comment: This is a nice solution for this particular problem!
As far as I interpreted the question its that the numbers 10\00\00\80 are always in that order, but not at the same place, therfore he had a problem with the string.split solution. IMHO a split from behind has the same difficulties with the undefined path length as the other way round. Maybe there are subfolders in future and we just don't know yet. Your solution would stop working and it has to be touched again, this would increase the maintenance costs for this part of code.

Comment: @oberfreak: True, but in the question he stated that the first part of the path changes, and the latter doesn't... It's a question of make it generic to handle all cases, or make it fit the spec. I decided not to over-engineer it.

Answer (score 4):

A compact way using **string.Join** and **Regex.Split.**

```
string text = @"C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg";
string newString = string.Join(null, Regex.Split(text, @"[^\d]"));    //10000080
```

Answer (score 2):

You can rely on array index if the last part always is the filename.
since the last part is always

array_name[array_name.length - 1]

the 4 parts before that can be found by

array_name[array_name.length - 2]

array_name[array_name.length - 3]

etc

Answer (score 1):

If you always want to combine the last four numbers, split the string (use \ as the separator), start counting from the last part and take 4 numbers, or the 4 almost last parts.

If you want to take *all* the digits, just scan the string from start to finish and copy just the digits to a new string.

Answer (score 1):

Using LINQ:

```
string path = @"C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg";
var parts = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Split('\\');
string numbersPart = parts.Skip(parts.Count() - 4)
                          .Aggregate((acc, next) => acc + next);
```

Result: "10000080"

Comment: +1: Just for using Linq... I'm too old fashioned and can't really use it on .NET 2.0, but it's nice reading Linq based answers :)

Answer (score 1):

```
string input = "C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg";
string[] parts = toSplit.Split(new char[] {'\\'});
IEnumerable<string> reversed = parts.Reverse();
IEnumerable<string> selected = reversed.Skip(1).Take(4).Reverse();
string result = string.Concat(selected);
```

The idea is to extract the parts, reverse them to keep only the last 4 (excluding the file name) and re reversing to rollback to the initial order, then concat.

Answer (score 1):

```
var r = new Regex(@"[^\d+]");

var match = r
    .Split(@"C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg")
    .Aggregate((i, j) => i + j);

return match.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

to find the number you can use regex:

```
(([0-9]{2})\\){4}
```

use concat all inner Group `([0-9]{2})` to get your searched number.

This will always find your searched number in any position in the given string.

Sample Code:

```
static class TestClass {
    static void Main(string[] args) {

        string[] tests = { @"C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\test.jpg",
        @"C:\Projects\test\whatever\files\media\10\00\00\80\some\foldertest.jpg",
        @"C:\10\00\00\80\test.jpg",
        @"C:\10\00\00\80\test.jpg"};

        foreach (string test in tests) {
            int number = ExtractNumber(test);
            Console.WriteLine(number);
        }
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static int ExtractNumber(string path) {
        Match match = Regex.Match(path, @"(([0-9]{2})\\){4}");
        if (!match.Success) {
            throw new Exception("The string does not contain the defined Number");
        }

        //get second group that is where the number is
        Group @group = match.Groups[2];

        //now concat all captures
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        foreach (var capture in @group.Captures) {
            builder.Append(capture);
        }

        //pares it as string and off we go!
        return int.Parse(builder.ToString());
    }
}
```